# Error in generate code and Update list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i Try to make generate 16 bit code and when i add the record all number is same how can i fix it ?

in loop befor  code[i] = Newcode; code is corect when code added in list changed last code to new so all code is same as last generate !!!!

```
public ActionResult Gen5Rm(GenerateCodeModel model){

        Code Newcode = new Code();

        int X = Convert.ToInt32(model.Quntity);

        Code[] code = new Code[X];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {      
                string strDate = "";
                string strmonth = "";
                string strday = "";
                string myday = "";

                strmonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
                myday = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();


                if (myday == "Sunday")
                {
                    strday = "SU";
                }
                if (myday == "Monday")
                {
                    strday = "MO";
                }
                if (myday == "Tuesday")
                {
                    strday = "TU";
                }
                if (myday == "Wednesday")
                {
                    strday = "WE";
                }
                if (myday == "Thursday")
                {
                    strday = "TU";
                }
                if (myday == "Friday")
                {
                    strday = "FR";
                }
                if (myday == "Saturday")
                {
                    strday = "ST";
                }
                strDate = generateBarcode();
                Newcode.codebase = model.Agent + strmonth +
            model.Type_Code + strDate + strday + "5" + model.Dealercode;
                Newcode.price = 5;
                Newcode.serial = "S" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmssfff");

                code[i] = Newcode;
         }

        return PartialView("_return5rm", code);
        }
```

[the export is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcrRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Newcode should be inside the for loop, otherwise all items in the array will point the same object (same memory address)

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{ 
    Code Newcode = new Code();
    ...
}
```